# How to manipulate a DropDownList DataTextField when bound to a cached string array

Tags: c#, arrays, caching

I have a dropdownlist bound to a cached string[], like so...

```
Cache["elems"] = items.elems;   //typeOf(items.elems)=string[]
DropDownList1.DataSource = Cache["elems"];
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

I want to limit the length of text displayed in DropDownList1  e.g. an element called "Manufacturing" would display "Manufact..." and have a value "Manufacturing"

How to do this?

Comment: Attach to the DataBound event and iterate through the items and trim the item text property accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mihai Caracostea I ended up with this...

```
    protected void DropDownList1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem myItem in DropDownList1.Items)
        {
            try
            {
                if (myItem.Text.Length > 8)
                    myItem.Text = myItem.Text.Substring(0, 11) + "...";
            }
            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex) 
            { 
                //do nothing
            }
        }
    }
```